# Return the inverse value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Using Ionic and Angular, I'm trying to create a directive that is built upon Ionic's Side Menu. Right now its being based off their fade-bar demo and looks like this.

```
.directive('fade', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            // Run in the next scope digest
            $timeout(function () {
                // Watch for changes to the openRatio which is a value between 0 and 1 that says how "open" the side menu is
                $scope.$watch('sideMenuController.getOpenRatio()', function (ratio) {
                    // Set the transparency of the fade bar
                    $element[0].style.opacity = Math.abs(ratio);
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
```

So right now the `.getOpenRatio` is keeping track of how open the side menu is. Now what I'm doing is trying to fade the Menu content out as that ratio changes to 1. But my issue is is that I don't know how to get the inverse of that value. So the Content's opacity is set the 0 when closed and 1 when open. [Here's my example](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/eabcy)

How can I get this to "say" that when the open ratio is 0, my contents opacity is 1, but when the ratio is 1, my contents opacity is 0. I don't know if this is built in to JavaScript so I am willing to add jQuery to the project if I need to.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `contentOpacity = 1 - ratio` ?

Comment: Wow that simple? I feel like and idiot ha. Thanks for the quick response. Want to answer it and I'll give the credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$element[0].style.opacity = 1 - Math.abs(ratio);
```